# Nuxeo on debian lenny

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, nuxeo

I have installed nuexo document control software on debian lenny. But when try to launch the application in browser http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/ it shows the error as below.

HTTP Status 404 - /nuxeo/

type Status report

message /nuxeo/

description The requested resource (/nuxeo/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

I am unable to identify the issue. Please help me to solve the issue. Waiting for reply.

Thanks in advance
caterpillar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I enabled this line in /etc/nuxeo-dm/nuxeo.conf

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

and restarted the service. It started working :-)